# C - Program terminates without scanf'ing?

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

Not really sure whats going on here, whether Im just being a fool or something odd with the compiler.

The code below should, after calling my searchList function, take input from the user, but instead the program just terminates, not even seg faulting, it literally just ends. Something silly?

EDIT: searchNode is searchList, sorry for typo.

Cheers.

```
typedef struct List {
 char c;
 struct List *next;
}List;

List* insertNode(char c, List* t1);
List* addNode(void);
List* searchList(List *t1);

int main(void) {
  List *z = addNode();
  List *search_result;
  char s;
   while ( z != NULL) {
    printf("%c", z->c);
    z = z->next;
  }
  search_result = searchList(z);
return 0;
}

List *addNode(void) {
 List *head = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
 char c;
 while (( c = getchar()) != '.') {
  head = insertNode(c, head);
 }
 return head;
}

List *insertNode(char c, List* t1) {
 List *tail = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
 tail->c = c;
 tail->next = t1;
return tail;
}

List *searchList(List *t1) {
 char c;
 printf("Please enter a search term");
 scanf("%c", &c);
  while (t1 != NULL) {
   if (t1->c == c) {
   return t1;
  }
  t1 = t1->next;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean SearchList, not SearchNode.

Comment: Can you post some output, too?  I see other 'getchar's in there.  Do those get hit?

Comment: The content gets added to the LinkedList fine, thats the getchar() functions use. But it seems when I call searchList, it prints Please Enter a Search Term, then just stops running.

Comment: Please use the debugger, it sometimes finds bugs even faster then SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program executes `getchar`, and `scanf` after it. After the execution of `getchar` you still have a `'\n'` in the buffer, and that's what `scanf` reads.

You can work around this by reading the characters from the buffer, after you've read the `.` character :

```
while (( c = getchar()) != '.') {
    head = insertNode(c, head);
}
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: But I need it to terminate at '.', not a new line.

Comment: Read the `'\n'` *after* you've terminated at `'.'`. See the code I just added.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `searchList` is made when `z` is `NULL`. Hence it returns immediately.

```
while ( z != NULL) {
    printf("%c", z->c);
    z = z->next;
}
search_result = searchList(z);
```

The `while` loop terminates when `z` equals `NULL`.

Your fundamental problem is that you don't have enough variables. You need to maintain a variable to point at the beginning of the list, and another variable to use when iterating over the list.

You also seem to be confusing head and tail. The term *tail* is used to denote the node for which `next` is `NULL`. The term *head* denotes the node at the other end of the list.

There are lots of other oddities in this code but I don't want to address them all because you only asked about one specific issue and I rather suspect that this is homework.

Comment: Aye, I have fixed that now, but stil can't overcome the problem of my program terminating when it hits the scanf statement.

Comment: @Igor has addressed that issue.

Comment: How can I get scanf to skip that \n, or reset the buffer containing it?